# Вывести картинку на весь экран Unity 5

Tags: c#, unity3d

Необходимо вывести (по команде в скрипте) картинку на весь экран. Перекрывающую всё.  Из задумок - только создать вторую камеру, поставить ей картинку как фон, в нужный момент - переключить на нее. Можно ли это сделать как нибудь проще?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да проще варианта особо и нет. Куда может быть проще включить (`SetActive(true)`) или отключить (`SetActive(false)`) что-то в нужный момент? Одна команда на одно действие и одна команда - на другое.

Единственное, чтоб не таскать лишнюю камеру и т.к. наверняка используете UI, то можно сразу этим самым UI и воспользоваться. Т.е.

- Добавляем к `Canvas` (т.е.к UI) пустой объект. Называем его *Overlay* и говорим его ширине и высоте занимать весь экран:

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- У этого объекта добавляем потомка `UI -> Image` (Image принимает себе не простую картинку, а sprite. Это значит нужно картинку сделать типом спрайт. Если хотите чистую картинку, можете вместо `Image` выбрать `RawImage`). Обзываем потока например *OverlayBackground*.

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

  которому можно назначить картинку или просто в монотонный цвет закрасить или сделать прозрачность.

---

И в итоге конкретно с этим *Overlay* делаем что хотим: скрываем, показываем, назначем бэкграунды для *OverlayBackground*, добавляем еще какие-нибудь объекты, например отображение результата игры или меню или кнопки выхода и прочее.

Ну и конечно включаем или выключаем в нужный момент.

---

Примерная иерархия:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! А как конкретно в скрипте его выключить или включить? Я понял что  `(SetActive(true))` или отключить `(SetActive(false))`  А как именно? Скрипт прикрепить к OverlayImage? А дальше?

Comment: @Dmitrii скрипт у вас может находится где угодно вообще, по сути. Может на игроке, может на камере, может на *GameManager* вообще. А отключать стоит не OverlayImage, а корень, т.е. *Overlay*, т.к. в нем может находится не только картинка на весь экран, но еще что-то (на ваше усмотрение конечно)...А выключать можно либо предварительно найти объект `GameObject.Find("/path/to/object").SetActive(false)`, либо например в скрипте у вас определено поле `public GameObject myOverlay `, в которое вы можете перетащить сам объект *Overlay* и уже в нужный момент написать `myOverlay.SetActive(false)` и т.д.

Comment: спасибо, с этим вопросом я быстро разобрался, поэтому успел его удалить. А как растянуть картинку? Я выбрал stretch в настройках UI, якорьки поставились по краям экрана а само изображение как было так и осталось маленьким. Пробовал вбить нужные значения в size - картинка расширяется, но ведь на разных устройствах разные разрешения экрана, можно как то просто растянуть до screen.height\screen.width?

Comment: @Dmitrii позицию надо у главного объекта поставить верхний левый угол (left = top = 0) и right = bottom = 0 тоже ... посмотрите в ответе.....у картинки в принципе тоже все по нулям лучше сделать

Comment: Добавлю так же от себя, что необходимо изначально убрать галочку в Overlay, а потом, уже в приложении включать его  в нужный момент командой `myOverlay.SetActive(true)`
Также важно сначала добавлять скрипт с кодом к чему либо( я добавил к игроку), а затем уже в инспекторе этого игрока ставить ему этот Overlay. Мелочи, а приходилось по полчаса додумывать, почему не работает.

Comment: @Dmitrii ну это как бы логично. перед тем как включить что-то надо его выключить .... перед тем как манипулировать чем-то - нужно иметь ссылку на него О_о Это ж база знаний

Answer (score 2):

Очень простое решение: используя `Image` (`GUI`) с `Canvas`'ом.

1. Добаляем в иерархии сцены новый UI->Image
2. Делаем его растягиваемым с помощью настроек привязок (делается в инспекторе объектов; нажимайте на квадратик сверху слева и выбирайте нужный вам вариант)
   [image: Настройка привязок в испекторе объекта]
3. Убедитесь, что изображение будет в самом низу списка элементов GUI в Canvas'е, иначе поверх изображения будут видны другие элементы GUI
4. Подключайте как вам удобнее изображение к вашему скрипту