# Перемещение объекта в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Доброго времени суток. Потихоньку изучаю Unity3D и разрабатываю простенькую 2D игру. При нажатии на кнопку паузы (вызов метода `Pause()`) в интерфейсе выскакивает затемненный фон, при клике по фону игра продолжается. Решил реализовать данную задачу так: фон как кнопка. Чтобы остальные элементы вне паузы под кнопкой были доступны, решил повесить на кнопку RigidBody2D и отодвигать/пододвигать фон паузы при кликах. Все вроде как получилось, но остались вопросы.

```
public Rigidbody2D back_pause = new Rigidbody2D();
bool pause = false;

void Start () {
//при старте сцены сразу отодвигаю фон паузы
back_pause.transform.position = Vector2.left * 3000f;
}

public void Pause(){
    if(pause == false){ //клик по кнопке "пауза"
        pause = true;
        back_pause.transform.position = Vector2.right * 3f;
    }else{              //клик по фону, отмена паузы
        pause = false;
        back_pause.transform.position = Vector2.left * 3000f;
    }
}
```

Как видно из кода вправо двигаем на 3f, влево на 3000f, разница в тысячу(!) раз, а в игре все работает как надо. Непонятно... Почему так происходит? Видимо я не правильно понимаю принцип перемещения и векторов... Может можно как то по другому осуществить задуманное?

Comment: Пока у меня нет ответа на вопрос про left/right, но на счет показать/убрать фон:  проще использовать `enable = true/false` чтоб просто отобразить объект на сцене или скрыть, а не сдвигать фон куда-то в сторону

Comment: Этот вариант я прорабатывал первым. При `enable = false` ведь кнопка не исчезает, а просто отключает свой функционал (невозможно кликнуть) и становится "вдавленной", но не пропадает...

Comment: Возможно я c `SetActive` спутал))  вот смотрите... можно просто фон расположить на весь экран http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/537964/191482   ........ у этого фона, если угодно детектить клик - можно воспользоваться eventTrigger https://youtu.be/3NBYqPAA5Es?t=189   и всё.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, про `eventTrigger` спасибо, не знал про него!) Я так понимаю вы имеете ввиду фон как Image, но ведь он тоже как и кнопка идет как слой,  и если его сделать невидимым `.CrossFadeAlpha(0, 0, false);`, через него нельзя будет кликнуть по элементам игры...

Comment: А зачем вам во время паузы кликать на элементы игры? Ведь пауза для того и делается, чтоб на них не кликать...... и невидимым (точнее не активным) делать лучше не `CrossFadeAlpha` а `SetActive(false)`...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, спасибо Вам большое! Ввиду своей малоопытности в Unity, я получается работал с голыми `Image` и `Button`, забыв, что можно использовать все прелести `GameObject`! Получается применив `.SetActive` к `GameObject` он полностью выключается со сцены. Теперь смогу сделать все задуманное, еще и плавное появление будет для красоты!        И там я имел ввиду, что элементы ВНЕ паузы оставались недоступны, т.к фон паузы оставался, но был прозрачен. Теперь `.SetActive` решает проблему) Оформите как ответ, отмечу!

Comment: вы можете, в принципе, сами опубликовать  развернутый ответ на свой вопрос. И через 30 часов принять ;-)  Думаю это имеет место быть

Answer (score 1):

Для создания менюх используй правильно настроенный Канвас + UI обьекты. Использование GUI обьектов не советую. Медленная и устаревшая технология.

для анимаций советую использовать LeanTween ассет. Анимирование оборачивается одним удовольствием + сама библиотека очень быстрая в работе и к тому же бесплатная. Для использования более красивых анимаций (не по линейной функции) используй  SetEase метод.